# cakephp 2.5.7 login->Auth always false even password is correct

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I was stuck in this problem for almost a week. Even going through all the solutions in the internet doesn't help me to solve my problem. So I decided to ask my problem here and hope I will get solution.

My problem is why i always get **Auth** `FALSE` even my password is correct? I manage to add a new user and it stores the encrypted password, but when I try to **login** using that `username` and `password, it displays "**Invalid username or password, try again**"

[**Here is my code**](https://gist.github.com/mrar160/07640881793259a77aae).

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some troubles with this part of cake as well, here is the way that I ended up using which works for me

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                'User.password' => Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], 'sha256', true)
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'User.id',
                'User.username',
                'User.group_id',
                // other fields you need
            )
        );

        $userData = $this->User->find('first', $options);
        if (!empty($userData) && $this->Auth->login($userData['User'])) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username, and/or password are incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

so, the bottom line is to manually check if the user with the given username and password exists, and then login them. Btw, pls pay attention that to `login()` function I am passing an array like this

```
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'group_id' => 2 
);
```

and not

```
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'group_id' => 2 
        ) 
    );
```

also, you do not want to pass the password to the `login` function if you are using cake 2.x, from cake docs
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

> In 2.x $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in
>   with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3
>   $this->Auth->login($this->data) would try to identify the user first
>   and only log in when successful.

so, first of all no need to pass the password, but you should be careful to check the valid user password before using `login` because if as it mentioned above, cake will login the user with **any data**.

About the password hashing part, please be sure you are using the same hashing algorithm with exact same salt (if you use it and you should) that you used during registration.

**edit:**

try using this in the model's beforeSave

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave($options);

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], 'sha256', true);
    }
}
```

For the last thing it is better practice to save a unique salt per user(salt should be saved in db along with user's password). In cake only one application side salt is being used for all passwords, and if the db and the app are compromised attacker can generate just one custom rainbow table for all passwords, but if the salt is unique for each user, then the bad guy should create custom rainbow table for each user separately, which is a lot more work/time/money.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dav.. BTW, it is work if i did not hash the password. But if used the hashing for the password, the password was not matched (when i try to login). The SQL statement show difference salt between the password stored in the DB. So, i suggest the hashing algorithm is not same.. But I used same hashing algorithm which is sha256.. Kindly could you help me again to find where is the difference in my Model and Controller in hashing part?..  I updated the UserController --> https://gist.github.com/mrar160/07640881793259a77aae

Comment: "so, the bottom line is to manually check if the user with the given username and password exists" And the way you do it you're *completely* losing the ability to use authentication adapters.

Comment: @razif pls see the updated answer, if this does not work, check your view file

Comment: @burzum, thanks for the comment, could u pls give a little more details about what specifically is wrong in doing so?

Comment: I would also very much advice against this approach. It destroys the whole idea of using clean and safe auth adapters. Please rather use the documented adapters, as they 100% work if you do it right (and that's not too difficult to do).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I've made changed in the model's beforeSave and also extend the varchar in the DB password field.. It work!!.. So, i will update this in my GitHub so other people who got same problem can refer the solution.. Thanks @dav and also thank to burzum

Comment: @mark, could you please help me understand where is the safety lose in here? thanks

Comment: @dav Read this page from there on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in But I would recommend to read the whole page to get an idea of how this works. There is nothing totally wrong but you won't be able to use two different ways  to login to your app the way you did it without additional and none-framework compliant code. The authorization and authentication adapters should be used to handle both scenarios.